# 'Create Clickable actions' JSON formatting not working

Tags: list, modern-experience, json-formatting, 2019, column-formatting

I am using SharePoint 2019. I want to create a clickable action column like referenced in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#create-clickable-actions.

For reference I rebuild the example given by Microsoft. When I insert the JSON formatting the content of my field disappears.

When I remove the @currentField the link works, but without the information of the field of course.

[image: Screenshots]

Now I'm wondering why it is not working, even though I rebuild the example given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using SharePoint 2019, Excel-style expressions will not work, hence you have to use Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) expressions.

So, use JSON like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": {
      "operator": "+",
      "operands": [
        "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",
        "@currentField"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Read more about excel style expressions and Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) expressions at:

1. [Excel-style expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#excel-style-expressions)
2. [Abstract Syntax Tree expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#abstract-syntax-tree-expressions)